# Executing a PHP file from a .GZ archive?

Tags: php

With PHP, Is it possible to extract to memory another PHP file from a .GZ, execute it and delete it from memory?

Suppose to have into the public html directory:
`index.php` and `site.gz`

Inside it, there are:

```
page.php
article.php
news.php
```

When I give `index.php?p=page1`

it extract page.php from the .gz file and put it into the memory (not on the Disk) , execute it, so that the user can have the generated content displayed, and then "destroyed" once have finished to be executed?

Comment: Is it really just a gzipped file? Or a compressed tarball? How was it created?

Comment: Just a gzipped file. My goal is to have everything packed in only one file, to be able to optimize portability

Answer (score 1):

If it's really a single `gzip -c` compressed file, then you can use [stream wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) to unpack and load a PHP script right away:

```
 include "compress.zlib://example.php.gz";
```

Otherwise [Phars](http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) are a more convenient alternative for distribution than e.g. plain zip/tar archives.

> Take note that you shouldn't use unvetted user input `$_GET["p"]` for including local files. (If that's what you're trying to do.)

Comment: yes but I need to use $_GET["p"] . Is there a way? and: I have not clue how to extract a file and use it at the fly, without saving it to the HD, execute it etc.